# Adjust Range Search of BinaryTree to get the Outer Elements

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I have a RedBlack [Balanced, sorted] Binary Tree and I am searching it to find all the values within the range [lower, upper].

```
public IEnumerable<TData> Range(
      BinaryTree<TData> root, 
      IComparer<TData> comparer, 
      TData lower, 
      TData upper)
{
    var stack = new Stack<State>(16);
    BinaryTree<TData> here = root;

    do
    {
        if (here == null)
        {
            if (stack.Count == 0)
                break;

            State popped = stack.Pop();
            yield return popped.Data;
            here = popped.Next;
            continue;
        }

        if (comparer.Compare(here.Data, lower) < 0)
        {
            here = here.Right;
        }
        else if (comparer.Compare(here.Data, upper) > 0)
        {
            here = here.Left;
        }
        else
        {
            stack.Push(new State {Next = here.Right, Data = here.Data});
            here = here.Left;
        }
    } while (true);  
}
```

So with this code, if I were to have a tree built with the values

```
 [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9],
```

and search for all elements within the range

```
 [3, 8]
```

I would get the following results:

```
 [4, 5, 6].
```

My question is how can I do about adjusting this algorithm in order to get the outer elements of the search? like this:

```
 [1, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

i.e. the value 3 lies between 1 and 4 in the tree, so I want to return 1, similarly the value 8 lies between 6 and 9 and I would want the value 9 to be includes in the result.

One catch is I don't want to restart the search from root

Currently implemented using NGenerics

[Edit]

Willing to accept a general algorithmic answer.

Comment: Is it a balanced (sorted) tree? That makes a huge difference.

Comment: Yes sorry, RedBlackTree

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with what you are trying to populate the Red Black Tree. But if you are using array or stream of data (whose number of elements will not change) then you may go this by using [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

```
class SegmentTree
{
    class Node
    {
        int max, min, s, e;
        Node left, right;

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            String str = "Min: "+this.min+" Max: "+this.max+" "+this.s+"-"+this.e;
            return str;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public SegmentTree() {}

    public SegmentTree(int[] array)
    {
        add(array);
    }

    public void add(int[] array)
    {
        root = add(0, array.length-1, array);
    }

    private Node add(int s, int e, int[] array)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.s = s;
        n.e = e;

        if(n.s==n.e)
        {
            n.min = n.max = array[n.s];
            return n;
        }

        int mid = s+(e-s)/2;
        n.left = add(s, mid, array);
        n.right = add(mid+1, e, array);
        n.max = Math.max(n.left.max, n.right.max);
        n.min = Math.min(n.left.min, n.right.min);

        return n;
    }


    // Get the max value between the limits l and r (both inclusive)
    public int getMax(int l, int r)
    {
        return getMax(root, l, r);
    }

    private int getMax(Node n, int l, int r)
    {
        if(l<=n.s && r>=n.e)
            return n.max;
        if(l>n.e || r<n.s)
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return Math.max(getMax(n.left, l, r), getMax(n.right, l, r));
    }   

    public int getMin(int l, int r)
    {
        return getMin(root, l, r);
    }

    private int getMin(Node n, int l, int r)
    {
        if(l<=n.s && r>=n.e)
            return n.min;
        if(l>n.e || r<n.s)
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return Math.min(getMin(n.left, l, r), getMin(n.right, l, r));
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

If there is increase or decrease in the data then you have to reconstruct the tree. If there is frequent insertion/ deletion/ updation then this is not at all a good choice.
This is very useful when you have set of data and on which you need to frequently check the values for the particular range.
I have given the example of storing both minimum and maximum value. You may store sum of values or any thing else in your `Node`
Apologize for writing code in JAVA :)